# How would I draw a Miniature 3d mockup of the player in MCP?

Tags: java, 3d, minecraft

[image: What I want]

How would I make an mini 3d mockup of the player in MCP like the above image, in a specific location?

I haven't been able to find any info on it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `GuiInventory.drawEntityOnScreen();`

There is a chance that it is private though, so if it is make sure to unprivate it.

Also if your drawing the player, make sure the player exists with like:

```
if(Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer != null) code();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();

EntityLivingBase target = (EntityLivingbase) mc.pointedEntity;

GuiInventory.drawEntityOnScreen(x, y, x, x, y, traget);
```

Credit:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOW8D3NEjpU-jBp0V_vAF5w